# ASP.NET Core hosted on IIS: how get user directory of app.pool identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

The ASP.NET Core 3.1 hosted on IIS server (OutOfProcess model) and ApplicationPool is configured to use specific Windows user (e.g. UserForIIS). Site uses Windows authentication.
If "UserForIIS" is logged in the system, then

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

returns correct Home directory of user "UserForIIS".
But if this user is not logged in (normal behavior), then this code returns Home directory for the "SYSTEM" user instead: "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile"

I suppose the problem is in the Kestrel server, but not 100% sure. Do anybody have ideas how to always get correct Home directory of the user specified as AppPool identity?

Comment: Why bother? Generally if we have a web application, we create a folder for it and we just update the configuration file to point to it. Depending on your needs, that could be something like `C:\mywebapp` or `\\myfileshare\mywebapp`.

Comment: Because it is the way this app is used. There are another desktop apps that put some files this site need in the users folder. Site must work with these files.

Comment: Having desktop apps and a web application run under the same user doesn’t sound like a good idea. The web application probably shouldn’t run under a desktop user account at all. – Just make the path configurable and give the web app user write permissions to the location. Then it won’t matter where your data is stored or what user it would need.